# Convert currencies with the exchange rate of a past date

Tags: currency

Is there a free/cheap service, accessible through a web service or simple HTTP/XML queries, that can convert from a currency to another, but with the exchange rate of a specific date in the past?
Say I need to know how much 10 USD was in EUR on date March, 13, 2009.
So far I've only found oanda.com offering this service to developers, but they cost 200$/mo, and my budget is lower.

ECB is cool! But it works if I need to convert from EUR to something. If I need to convert from GBP to something elase I'll have to find another time series :( Isn't there a service or time series provider to convert from any currency to any other currency, for a certain date? Like OANDA actually, just cheaper :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replying to myself, I found this:
http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html

You can download a single CSV file with all daily exchange rates from euro to anything...since 1999! Very cool.

Comment: ECB is cool! But it works if I need to convert from EUR to something. If I need to convert from GBP to something elase I'll have to find another time series :( Isn't there a service or time series provider to convert from any currency to any other currency, for a certain date? Like OANDA actually, just cheaper :)

Comment: ECB has both GBP and USD in EUR, so to convert from GBP to USD you just have to go through Euros. Or do you need a currency that's not in there?

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to try out Google AppEngine anyway, so I made an app for this, using [the ECB rates](http://www.ecb.int/stats/exchange/eurofxref/html/index.en.html) from 1999 onwards:

http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/getrate/2009-11-15/usd/zar

gives you the value of 1 USD in ZAR on 2009-11-15. See [this page for the full docs](http://currencies.apps.grandtrunk.net/).

**EDIT**

I just threw in [the Fed's rates](http://www.federalreserve.gov/RELEASES/H10/Hist/), going back to 1971...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try with Yahoo Finance web service for developers

http://developer.yahoo.com/

Answer (score 0):

The USA government gives away some of this kind of data.

http://www.federalreserve.gov/RELEASES/H10/Hist/

Answer (score 0):

www.xe.com
go to historical rates